# Saving a Parse object within a for loop does save all the objects

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have the following code where I am trying to save personalities of a movie. Only few personalities get created and saved.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Movie);

query.find({ success: function(movies) {
    console.log("movies.length " + movies.length );
    for (var movieIterator = 0; movieIterator < movies.length ; movieIterator++) {

        cast_array = movies[movieIterator].get("cast");
        console.log(cast_array);

        for (var i = 0; i < cast_array.length; i++) {
            var personalityObj = new Personality();
            personalityObj.set('name', cast_array[i].trim());
            personalityObj.save();  // NOt all personalities get saved
        }

    }
    response.success("Awesome");
}, error: function(error) {
    response.error(error)
}});
```

How may I improve the code so that all the personalities get stored/saved in the DB.

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/create-multiple-rows-through-cloudcode  see answer for save on obj array

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this and let me know if it works.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Movie);

query.find({ success: function(movies) {
    console.log("movies.length " + movies.length );
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < movies.length ; i++) {

        cast_array = movies[i].get("cast");
        console.log(cast_array);

        for (var j = 0; j < cast_array.length;j++) {
            var personalityObj = new Personality();
            personalityObj.set('name', cast_array[j].trim());
            list.push(personalityObj);
        }

    }
    Parse.Object.saveAll(list).then(function(results){
        console.log("Objects were saved!");
        response.success("Awesome");
    },function(eerror){
        console.log(eerror);
        response.error(eerror);
    });

}, error: function(error) {
    response.error(error);
}});
```

The above code is using saveAll function for batch operation. [Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Object.html#.saveAll)